# SwiftUI Setting Bind<String> in Text field

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've got the following object that contain list of strings:

```
class handler: ObservableObject {
  @Published var items = [String]()
}
```

In some closure, I set this list with valid values :

```
for item in item_list! {
  self.handler.items.append(item.stringData)
}
```

and in the ContentView part I've got `Picker` that support to present that list of strings in realtime:

```
VStack {
  Picker("items", selection: $arg1) {
    ForEach($handler.items, id: \.self) {
      Text($0)
    }
  }
}
```

However, it fails to compile due to the following reason :

`Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding<String>' conform to 'StringProtocol'`

Any Idea how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need binding here to loop items, instead use `handler` directly (ie. without `$`), like

```
ForEach(handler.items, id: \.self) {    // << here !!
  Text($0)
}
```